# Manual install and dependency check of packets (Slackware)

Tags: linux, installation, slackware

I have this homework, which asks me to install knockd and other packets on a super old version of Slackware (Kernel v. 2.6.15.4). The task description specifically mentions that we are not allowed to use install software which performs dependency checks like apt-get, although conveniently omits any mention of documentation on how a manual install of a package is properly performed. As I'm still pretty much a noob Linux user, I would be very thankful for a process description of how to do this the proper way.

Many thanks in advance!

Dave

Comment: Have you at least googled the answer? for instance "slackware check dependencies"?

Comment: Well, of course I did some googling, and, yes, there are links on the topic, but all of them require more prior knowledge than I currently have. Pretty much every installation I have ever done involved install wizards or package managers. I don't want to ruin anything on the system and hoped, that somebody here might point me to a good book or article on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two ways to do this:

- install an old version of knockd that should be working with your old kernel
- get the source from GIT and compile it yourself

In general, if it compiles, you can run it. So the last is the surest. Also, look at the GIT-repository, which suggests:

> To build knockd, make sure you have libpcap and the autoconf tools installed.

It also shows the magic incantations

```
$ autoreconf -fi
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

which should be known to all Linux wizards that use the source.